# Matrix chain Multiplication error while varying the size of matrices

Tags: matrix-multiplication

I am writing a matrix chain multiplication code.
In this first i am taking input from user the no of matrices and their dimensions
then its sequential product is calculated,then matrix chain order is calculated.
After that the matrices are multiplied based on the matrix chain order.
But following error occurs while varying the matrix dimensions.
for ex:
complete multiplication and program ran successfully for
2 matrix of order 10*13 13*10
3 matrices of order 2*3 3*2 2*2
3 matrices of order 10*13 13*10 10*13
7 matrices each of order 12*12

matrix couldn't do just last step of product by MCM order for 
5 matrices of order 12*4 4*16 16*9 9*12 12*15
6 matrices of order 19*19 and 7th matrix 19*20
15 matrices of order 12*12

sequential wasn't done for 
6 matrices of order 3*3 3*4 4*11 11*13 13*7 7*12

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<time.h>
    int n,count;
    int **a;
    double ***b,***bz;
    struct stack
    {
         int *s;
         int top;
    };
    struct stack st,ss;
   void push(struct stack *stk,int item)
   {
         if(stk->top==(3*n-2)-1)
         printf("stack overflow");
         stk->top++;
         stk->s[stk->top]=item;
   }
   int pop(struct stack *stk)
   {
         stk->top--;
         return(stk->s[(stk->top)+1]);
   }
   void init_stack(struct stack *stk)
   {
         stk->top=-1;
         stk->s=(int *) malloc((3*n-2)*sizeof(int));
   }

   void print_opt_parens(int **s,int i,int j);    
   void matrix_chain_order(int p[],int length)
   {
         int n=length-1;
         int i,j,k,l,q,**mal,**sal;
         mal=(int **) malloc((n)*sizeof(int *));
         sal=(int **) malloc((n)*sizeof(int *));
         for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
                 mal[i]=(int *) malloc((n)*sizeof(int));
         for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
                 sal[i]=(int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
         for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
                 mal[i][i]=0;
         for(l=2;l<=n;l++)
         {
                 for(i=1;i<=n-l+1;i++)
                 {
                       j=i+l-1;
                       mal[i][j]=9999999;
                       for(k=i;k<=j-1;k++)
                       {
                              q=mal[i][k]+mal[k+1][j]+p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];
                              if(q < mal[i][j])
                              {
                                    mal[i][j]=q;
                                    sal[i][j]=k;
                              }
                       }        
                 }
          }
          printf("\n Optimal Number of Operations = %d",mal[1][n]);
          printf("\nprinting optimal parenthesis : \n");
          print_opt_parens(sal,1,n);
          return;
     }
     void mul(int x,int y);
     void print_opt_parens(int **s,int i,int j)
     {    int x,y,zz;

          if(i==j){
          printf(" A%d ",i);
          push(&st,i);
     } 
     else
     {
          printf(" ( ");
          push(&st,-1);
          print_opt_parens(s,i,s[i][j]);
      print_opt_parens(s,s[i][j]+1,j);
      printf(" ) ");
      x=pop(&st);
      y=pop(&st);
    mul(x,y);
    zz=pop(&st);
    if(x<0&&y<0)
                push(&st,(x+y));
    else if(x>0&&y>0)
                push(&st,-(x+y));
             else        
                push(&st,(x*y));     
     }
    }
     void init_b(double ***b)
      {
         int i,j,k;
           bz=(double ***) malloc((2*n)*sizeof(double **));
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                bz[i]=(double **) malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                 for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                                 bz[i][j]=(double *) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                 for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                                 for(k=0;k<n;k++)
                           bz[i][j]k]=0.0;                                             
                   count=-1;
              }
          void mul(int x,int y)
          {
              FILE *fp4,*fp5,*fp6;
             double **z,**tx,**ty;
             int m,l,i,j,k,mm,ll,kk,nn;
              if(x<0)
                 {
             mm=pop(&ss);
             nn=pop(&ss);
             tx=(double **) malloc(nn*sizeof(double));
             for(i=0;i<nn;i++)
                              tx[i]=(double *) malloc(mm*sizeof(double));

             for(i=0;i<nn;i++)
                              for(j=0;j<mm;j++){
                                               tx[i][j]=bz[count][i][j];
                                               }
             count--;
              }
               else
              {           
             mm=a[0][x-1];
             nn=a[1][x-1];
             tx=(double **) malloc(mm*sizeof(double));
             for(i=0;i<mm;i++)
                              tx[i]=(double *) malloc(nn*sizeof(double));
             for(i=0;i<mm;i++)
                              for(j=0;j<nn;j++){
                                               tx[i][j]=b[x-1][i][j];
                                               }
             } 
              if(y<0) 
           {
             kk=pop(&ss);
             ll=pop(&ss);
             ty=(double **) malloc(kk*sizeof(double));
             for(i=0;i<kk;i++)
                              ty[i]=(double *) malloc(ll*sizeof(double));

             for(i=0;i<kk;i++)
                              for(j=0;j<ll;j++){
                                               ty[i][j]=bz[count][i][j];
                                              }

             count--;
             }
              else
               {
             kk=a[0][y-1];
             ll=a[1][y-1];
             ty=(double **) malloc(kk*sizeof(double));
             for(i=0;i<kk;i++)
                              ty[i]=(double *) malloc(ll*sizeof(double));
             for(i=0;i<kk;i++)
                              for(j=0;j<ll;j++){
                                               ty[i][j]=b[y-1][i][j];

                                               }

                      }
           count++;
             bz[count]=(double **) realloc(bz[count],mm*sizeof(double *));
             for(i=0;i<mm;i++)
             bz[count][i]=(double *) realloc(bz[count][i],ll*sizeof(double));    

            for(i=0;i<kk;i++)
               {
             for(j=0;j<nn;j++)
             {                  
                              bz[count][i][j]=0;
                              for(k=0;k<mm;k++)
                              {
                                                bz[count][i][j]+=ty[i][k]*tx[k][j];
                              }
             }
            }

              fp6=fopen("g.txt","w+");

           for(i=0;i<kk;i++)
             {
                  for(j=0;j<nn;j++)
                  {

                                   fprintf(fp6,"%lf\t",bz[0][i][j]);
                  }
                  fprintf(fp6,"\n");

            }
          push(&ss,nn);
           push(&ss,kk);

           }   

         int main()
         {
              FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp3;
              int i,j,k,l,m,p,q;
              double **c,**t;
               int *pa;
               time_t ts;
             srand(time(&ts));
            // getting no of matrcies
            printf("\n Enter the Number or matrices :");
             scanf("%d",&n);
               // allocation of space to store matrices of varying rows and columns
             a=(int **) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
            init_b(bz);
           init_stack(&st);
           init_stack(&ss);
             for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                a[i]=(int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

              printf("\n Enter the rows and columns \n");
             for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                 for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                                scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);

            // verifying the multiplicability of the matrices
           for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
                if(a[1][i]!=a[0][i+1])
                {               

                                printf("The matrices %d and %d cannot be multiplied",i,i+1);
                                getch();
                                exit(0);
                }
          // actual matrix allocation                                       
b=(double ***) malloc(n*sizeof(double **));
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                b[i]=(double **) malloc(a[0][i]*sizeof(double *));
for(i=0;i<n;i<i++)
                  for(j=0;j<a[0][i];j++)
                                        b[i][j]=(double *) malloc(a[1][i]*sizeof(double));
// data entry
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                for(j=0;j<a[0][i];j++)
                                      for(k=0;k<a[1][i];k++)
                                                            b[i][j][k]=(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
//file opening
fp1=fopen("b.txt","w");
fp2=fopen("c.txt","w");
//print data
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
                for(j=0;j<a[0][i];j++)
                {
                                      for(k=0;k<a[1][i];k++){
                                                            if(fp1!=NULL)
                                                                         fprintf(fp1,"%lf\t",b[i][j][k]);
                                                            printf("%lf\t",b[i][j][k]);
                                      }
                                      printf("\n");
                                      fprintf(fp1,"\n");
                }
                printf("\n");
                fprintf(fp1,"\n");
}

// allocating space for temp, and result variable
c=(double **) malloc(a[0][0]*sizeof(double));
for(i=0;i<a[0][0];i++)
                c[i]=(double *) malloc(a[1][1]*sizeof(double));
t=(double **) malloc(a[0][0]*sizeof(double));
for(i=0;i<a[0][0];i++)
                t[i]=(double *) malloc(a[1][0]*sizeof(double));
// assigning initial value of t
for(i=0;i<a[0][0];i++)
                for(j=0;j<a[1][0];j++)
                                      t[i][j]=(double)b[0][i][j];
// sequential matrix multiplication      
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
                 c=(double **) realloc(c,a[0][0]*sizeof(double));
                 for(m=0;m<a[0][0];m++)
                 {
                                       c[m]=(double *) realloc(c[m],a[1][i]*sizeof(double));}
                for(j=0;j<a[0][0];j++)
                {
                                      for(k=0;k<a[1][i];k++)
                                      {
                                                            c[j][k]=0.0;
                                                            for(l=0;l<a[0][i];l++)
                                                            {                     
                                                                                  c[j][k]+=(double)t[j][l]*(double)b[i][l][k];
                                                            }
                                      }
                }
                t=(double **) realloc(t, a[0][0]*sizeof(double));
                for(m=0;m<a[0][i-1];m++)
                                       t[m]=(double *) realloc(t[m],a[1][i]*sizeof(double));
                for(m=0;m<a[0][0];m++)
                                        for(p=0;p<a[1][i];p++)
                                                              t[m][p]=c[m][p];
}
free(c);
free(t);
// print the result
for(i=0;i<a[0][0];i++)
{
                      for(j=0;j<a[1][n-1];j++){
                                              if(fp2!=NULL)
                                                           fprintf(fp2,"%lf\t",c[i][j]); 
                                              printf("%lf\t",c[i][j]);
                      }
                      printf("\n");
                      fprintf(fp2,"\n");
}
// extract the no of rows and columns
pa=(int *) malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));
pa[0]=a[0][0];
for(i=1;i<n+1;i++)
                  pa[i]=a[1][i-1];
//Matrix Chain OPerations and Order
matrix_chain_order(pa,n+1);
fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);         
getch();
return 0;
 }
```